# If $|x_1-x_0|<R$, then the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n \cdot a_n(x-x_0)^{n-1}$ converges absolutely at $x_1$.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, functions, power-series

I have a long question regarding the power series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n(x-x_0)^n$.

Let $0 \le R \le \infty$ be the convergence radius of the power series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n(x-x_0)^n$.

In the first question I have successfully proved that for $|q|<1$ the limit $\lim_{n \to \infty}[n \cdot q^n]=0$, while using the power series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n \cdot x^n$ .

Now I have this question:

If $|x_1-x_0|<R$, then the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n \cdot a_n(x-x_0)^{n-1}$ converges absolutely at $x_1$.
Consider $q=\frac{|x_1-x_0|}{|x_2-x_0|}$ where $|x_1-x_0|<|x_2-x_0|<R$

I have tried to use the things I have proved above, but I don't have any clue on what to do.

I will appreciate some hints on how to prove this.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What does $R$ stand for?

Comment: @Gary The Radius of convergence, I will edit that. Thanks.

Comment: I would just show that the radius of convergence is again $R$.

Comment: @Gary Alright, but how should I use $q$ in this case?

Comment: Isn't the series in question the derivative of the power series $\sum a_n(x-x_0)^n$ ?

Comment: @YathirajSharma Yes it is, but I am not allowed to use derivatives yet.

Answer (score 2):

Since $\left|x_{2}-x_{0}\right|<R$, We know that $\displaystyle{{\displaystyle \sum_{n=N}^{\infty}a_{n}\left(x_{2}-x_{0}\right)^{n}}}$ converges absolutely. 
Let $q=\left|\frac{x_{1}-x_{0}}{x_{2}-x_{0}}\right|<1$. as you already showed, $\displaystyle{\lim_{n\to\infty}nq^{n}=0}$ ,that is, there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$  such that $\forall n\ge N$ we have
$$\left|n\cdot\left(\frac{x_{1}-x_{0}}{x_{2}-x_{0}}\right)^{n}\right|<\left|x_{1}-x_{0}\right|\;\;\;\left(*\right)$$

Hence:
$$\sum_{n=N}^{\infty}\left|n\cdot a_{n}\left(x_{1}-x_{0}\right)^{n-1}\right|=\sum_{n=N}^{\infty}\left|n\cdot a_{n}\left(\frac{x_{1}-x_{0}}{x_{2}-x_{0}}\right)^{n}\cdot\frac{\left(x_{2}-x_{0}\right)^{n}}{x_{1}-x_{0}}\right|\underset{\left(*\right)}{\le}\sum_{n=N}^{\infty}\left|a_{n}\left(x_{2}-x_{0}\right)^{n}\right|<\infty$$
Namely, the power series converges absolutely at $x_1$

Comment: Thank you for your answer! About the inequality with $(*)$, I think you might mean to $\frac{1}{|x_1-x_0|} \sum_{n=N}^\infty |a_n (x_2-x_0)^n|$, am I correct?

Comment: Yes! i'll fix that shortly, thank you

Comment: @CalculusLover I made it even better, check it out.

Comment: No, thank you! Just notice that $|x_1-x_0|$ can be less than $1$ so its better the first way you did it.

Comment: why is that a problem if its smaller than $1$?

Comment: For example, take $|x_1-x_0|=\frac{1}{2}$, then $\frac{1}{0.5} \sum_{n=N}^\infty |a_n (x_2-x_0)^n| \ge \sum_{n=N}^\infty |a_n (x_2-x_0)^n|$

Comment: But the limit implies that there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$  such that $\forall n\ge N$ we have
$\left|n\cdot\left(\frac{x_{1}-x_{0}}{x_{2}-x_{0}}\right)^{n}\right|<\left|x_{1}-x_{0}\right|$

Comment: In other words, at the $(*)$ transition, just replace $\left|n\cdot\left(\frac{x_{1}-x_{0}}{x_{2}-x_{0}}\right)^{n}\right|$ with $\left|x_{1}-x_{0}\right|$ and see what you get

Comment: I will think about it, Thanks!

Comment: No problem, but since you insist on the $1$ thing, do you agree that $\left|n\cdot\left(\frac{x_{1}-x_{0}}{x_{2}-x_{0}}\right)^{n}\right|<\left|x_{1}-x_{0}\right|$ implies $\left|n\cdot\left(\frac{x_{1}-x_{0}}{x_{2}-x_{0}}\right)^{n}\cdot\frac{1}{x_{1}-x_{0}}\right|<1\;$ by dividing both sides? This yields the result and I hope its clear now.

Comment: Oh yes it is! Thank you for that!

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$
\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {n\left| {a_n } \right|\left| {x_1  - x_0 } \right|^{n-1} }  = \frac{1}{q}\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {nq^n \left| {a_n } \right|\left| {x_2  - x_0 } \right|^{n-1} } .
$$
You showed that $nq^n \to 0$. Thus there is an $N>0$ such that $nq^n <1$ for all $n\geq N$. Therefore,
\begin{align*}
\sum\limits_{n = N}^\infty  {n\left| {a_n } \right|\left| {x_1  - x_0 } \right|^{n-1}} & = \frac{1}{q}\sum\limits_{n = N}^\infty  {nq^n \left| {a_n } \right|\left| {x_2  - x_0 } \right|^{n-1} } \\ & \le \frac{1}{q|x_2-x_0|}\sum\limits_{n = N}^\infty  {\left| {a_n } \right|\left| {x_2  - x_0 } \right|^n }  <  + \infty .
\end{align*}
since the original power series is absolutely convergent for $|x-x_0|<R$. Thus, the radius of convergence is at least $R$. It is easy to see that it cannot be larger than that.

Comment: Thank you Gary, that helps!